# Json response is giving wrong data

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I am calling the webservice string using the `NSURLConnection` , I am getting wrong data in response in success method of `NSURLConnection` , But if i load same `URL` in browser i am getting correct response. I am using below code .

```
    NSData *mydata=[srtRes dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *e;
    NSMutableArray *returnArry =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    returnArry = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mydata options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
```

How to resolve this issue. Kindly give suggestion and answers.

Comment: is your json syntactically correct? you've verified it? else do it at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: if i give particular url in validator its was coming correct data why not in my code.

Comment: not necessarily, you are loading the data first, invalid JSON is valid data

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
  // In .h class
  @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData *responseData;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *temp_arr;

  // In .m class
  @synthesize responseData;
  @synthesize temp_arr;

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
     NSString *urlString=@"http://your urls";
     self.responseData=[NSMutableData data];
     NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] delegate:self];
     NSLog(@"connection====%@",connection);
  }
```

Delegate Method of JSON Parsing :

```
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
 }
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 {
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
 }  
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
    self.responseData=nil;
 }
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
     NSArray * returnArry = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
      NSDictionary *nameDic = nil;
     for (int i = 0 ; i < [returnArry count]; i++)
     {
        nameDic = [returnArry objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.temp_arr addObject:[nameDic objectForKey:@"name"]];  // According your key you have to save data in temp_arr.
     }
 }
```

Please follow this , if any doubt let me know :)